# How to stop DataGrid collapsing RowDetails on property change?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Given a DataGrid with a toggle row details button. Why does it collapse the details whenever a property is changed?

It collapses details whenever an column uses:

```
UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus
```

Also it collapses it whenever a property is updated in the details view.

Is there a way to keep it open? The row is still selected.

**XAML:**

```
RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Collapsed"

                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button x:Name="buttonDetails" Content="Hello" ButtonBase.Click="Details_Click"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

**C#:**

```
    // Load stuff from db
    _context.JobCollection.Load();

    // Set source with db stuff
    jobViewSource.Source = _context.JobCollection.Local;



    private void Details_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // the original source is what was clicked.  For example 
            // a button.
            DependencyObject dep = (DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource;

            // iteratively traverse the visual tree upwards looking for
            // the clicked row.
            while ((dep != null) && !(dep is DataGridRow))
            {
                dep = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dep);
            }

            // if we found the clicked row
            if (dep != null && dep is DataGridRow)
            {
                // get the row
                DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dep;

                // change the details visibility
                if (row.DetailsVisibility == Visibility.Collapsed)
                {
                    row.DetailsVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }
                else
                {
                    row.DetailsVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception)
        {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Few suggested changes :

1. Apply  `RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Collapsed"` to your DataGrid.
2. You Button click should look like this :

   ```
   private void Details_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
      DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)Dgrd1.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(Dgrd1.SelectedItem);

      if (row.DetailsVisibility == System.Windows.Visibility.Visible)
          row.DetailsVisibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
      else
          row.DetailsVisibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
   }
   ```

Comment: Already have this. Doesn't answer the question. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Post your XAML code. Or post your code at dropbox and post link in comment.

Comment: @flux i have made a sample app exactly as you described.

Comment: do you see the problem?

Comment: @flux see the sample app : https://www.dropbox.com/s/vttmmzf1j4wdvbp/WpfApplication1.rar?dl=0

Comment: Thanks. I now know it is something else in my code, possibly something to do with Entity Framework.

Comment: The issue occurs when using the PropertyChangedEventHandler (with the NotifyPropertyChanged method on the properties).